# PHP Foreach issue not formatting in array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a `php` function that's behaving unexpectedly. I'm running a `foreach` inside a `foreach` and printing out the result.

It looks as if the `print_r()` function is printing the first array data outside of the second `foreach`.

Can anyone help as it seems to be a common thing with what I'm working on today.

PHP code is:

```
foreach( $_SESSION['cart_items'] as $item ) {

                foreach( $item as $key => $product ) {

                    print_r($product);
                    # code...
                }
                # code...
            }
```

Output looks like:

```
401All Change Boys50
Array 
( 
[item_id] => 401 
[item_name] => All Change Boys 
[item_qty] => 20 
) 
Array ( 
[item_id] => 448 
[item_name] => Living My Life – The Exhibition 
[item_qty] => 2 
)
```

It looks like the first array isn't being formatted like the once below it. Thanks

Comment: Is there no other output being done prior to this code running? It also looks like it's duplicating that first element, which leads me to believe there's other output going on

Comment: Thats all - I'm at the top of the script where this function is going on

Comment: have you try to view source to see whats going on

Comment: There has to be other code that is doing the printing of the "401All Change Boys50" that you are not including in your question. Please include ALL of your code.

Comment: yeah, include more code please, because it looks as if you are printing only arrays, remember the print_r function prints information about variable, not only the value of variable, when you try to print an array with print_r, you can see something like your output, then include more code please.